# strptime() returns NA for char string - Locale language issue, Brazil Portuguese

Tags: r, strptime

First of all, I'm below starter level and am just starting to learn coding.

I'm tring to convert a character string into time using `strptime()` as follows:

```
t3 <- "October 17, 1986 08:24"
t4 <- strptime(t3, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")

t4

class(t4)
```

This is what it prints:

```
t3 <- "October 17, 1986 08:24"

t4 <- strptime(t3, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")

t4
[1] NA

class(t4)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

I'm using this on a scripted class - `swirl()` - and even though `t4` returns `NA`, it accepted as a correct answer to the task.

Tried using R Studio, R 3.3.1 and running R on a command line, as shown on the picture. (stack won't let me post it since my reputation is still low)

I also tried assigning "outubro" and "Outubro" to `t3` since my locale is Brazil.

Comment: I can't replicate this. It works fine over here on R 3.2.4.

Comment: I tried it again on R 3.3.1 and R Studio and it fails. Does local have anything to do with the result?

Comment: This is really core R functionality. I'd be extremely surprised if it isn't working without some other factor being changed. Can you start a basic command line or terminal and run `R` and then test your code?

Comment: It works on R 3.3.0 as well

Comment: Please check the picture I posted as answer below. I tried and got the same print.

Comment: You're working in Portuguese I presume - `%B` is locale specific, so it won't recognise "October" in English. It will be looking for "Outubro" or whatever the equivalent is. You might want to change your locale in R so it uses English, or use local date formats as input.

Comment: I tried as you're suggesting, with both capital and small "o", since in Portuguese we don't need capitals for months. Heres the print: 

`> t3 <- "Outubro 17, 1986 08:24

> t3
[1] "Outubro 17, 1986 08:24"
> t4
[1] NA
> t3 <- "outubro 17, 1986 08:24"
> t4
[1] NA`

Comment: @CésarGalvão - I'm pretty sure it's still the issue - you can check your local month names via `format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B")` to see if it matches up.

Comment: @thelatemail thank you so much. the `format` returned "outubro" for month 10 and it didn't work at first. Test 1 didn't work but, odd enough, rewriting the script made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thelatemail recommended me to check local month names via `format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B")`

My locale and language were the issue. In Portuguese, months should be used without capital letters.

Now:

`t3 <- "outubro 17, 1986 08:24"
t4 <- strptime(t3, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")
[1] "1986-10-17 08:24:00 BRT"`